# How to use controller_manager with ros_canopen

Tags: ros, ros-control, ros-kinetic, ros-canopen, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently working on controlling two dc motors with integrated controller using ros_canopen, ROS kinetic, ubuntu 16.04.

So far I have done steps 1 through 7 in [THIS](https://answers.ros.org/question/250174/how-to-control-maxon-motor-by-using-ros_canopen/) answer. But I am stuck at the controller_manager part of getting it to work.

Just a tiny recap, I have made an URDF, made driver and controller configs, launched canopen_motor_node and i am able to use init, get/set_object and the other services canopen_motor_node provides.

However, as I am trying to control a diff drive robot I would like to use the diff_drive_controller so I have made the following config file for the controller:

```
raw19:
  mobile_base_controller:
    type        : "diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController"
    #topic        : "test"
    left_wheel  : 'motor1'
    right_wheel : 'motor2'
    publish_rate: 50.0               # default: 50
    pose_covariance_diagonal : [0.001, 0.001, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000.0]
    twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000.0]
    required_drive_mode: 2

    # Wheel separation and diameter. These are both optional.
    # diff_drive_controller will attempt to read either one or both from the
    # URDF if not specified as a parameter
    wheel_separation : 0.42
    wheel_radius : 0.1313

    # Wheel separation and radius multipliers
    wheel_separation_multiplier: 1.0 # default: 1.0
    wheel_radius_multiplier    : 1.0 # default: 1.0

    # Velocity commands timeout [s], default 0.5
    cmd_vel_timeout: 0.25

    # Base frame_id
    base_frame_id: base_link #default: base_link

    # Velocity and acceleration limits
    # Whenever a min_* is unspecified, default to -max_*
    linear:
      x:
        has_velocity_limits    : true
        max_velocity           : 1.0  # m/s
        min_velocity           : -1.0 # m/s
        has_acceleration_limits: true
        max_acceleration       : 0.8  # m/s^2
        min_acceleration       : -0.8 # m/s^2
        has_jerk_limits        : true
        max_jerk               : 5.0  # m/s^3
    angular:
      z:
        has_velocity_limits    : true
        max_velocity           : 0.7  # rad/s
        has_acceleration_limits: true
        max_acceleration       : 0.5  # rad/s^2
        has_jerk_limits        : true
        max_jerk               : 2.5  # rad/s^3
```

I have tried following the edit/answer of [THIS](https://answers.ros.org/question/293260/controller-manager-how-to-correctly-launch-it/)  question and [THIS](https://answers.ros.org/question/289561/help-to-run-diff_drive_controller/) video/answer but I can't seem to get it to work. But i don't if that is because I am not using Gazebo. I think my main issue is understanding ros_control/controller_manager and how to initiate/spawn the controllers. My preliminary thoughts are that the error is in my launch or urdf file.

Launch file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

    <arg name="model" default="$(find robot)/urdf/rawcopy.xacro" />
    <arg name="rvizconfig" default="$(find robot)/rviz/urdf.rviz" />

  <!-- send urdf to param server -->
  <param name="/raw19/robot_description" 
     command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(arg model) --inorder" />

  <!-- robot state publisher -->
  <node ns="raw19"
    pkg="robot_state_publisher" 
    type="robot_state_publisher" 
    name="robot_state_publisher"/>

  <node ns="raw19"
    name="joint_state_publisher" 
    pkg="joint_state_publisher" 
    type="joint_state_publisher"
    output="screen"/>

  <!-- canopen_motor_node -->
  <node ns="raw19" 
        name="driver" 
        pkg="canopen_motor_node" 
        type="canopen_motor_node" 
        output="screen" 
        clear_params="true" 
        launch-prefix="">
     <rosparam command="load" file="$(find robot)/config/driver_config.yaml" />
  </node>


  <!-- controllers -->
  <rosparam command="load" 
        file="$(find robot)/config/diff_controller.yaml" />


  <!-- load_controllers -->
  <node ns="raw19"
    name="controller" 
    pkg="controller_manager" 
    type="controller_manager" 
    args="spawn
          joint_state_controller
          mobile_base_controller" 
    respawn="false" 
    output="screen"/>

  <!-- Show in Rviz   -->
  <node ns="raw19"
    name="rviz" 
    pkg="rviz" 
    type="rviz" 
    args="-d $(arg rvizconfig)" 
    required="true" />

</launch>
```

When i launch and run 'rostopic list' and 'rosservice list' I just get the following. I would expect to get at least two services a la '*/command'. Am I wrong to assume this?

```
/clicked_point
/diagnostics
/initialpose
/move_base_simple/goal
/raw19/joint_states
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
/tf_static
```

rosservice list:

```
/raw19/controller/get_loggers
/raw19/controller/set_logger_level
/raw19/driver/get_loggers
/raw19/driver/get_object
/raw19/driver/halt
/raw19/driver/init
/raw19/driver/recover
/raw19/driver/set_logger_level
/raw19/driver/set_object
/raw19/driver/shutdown
/raw19/joint_state_publisher/get_loggers
/raw19/joint_state_publisher/set_logger_level
/raw19/robot_state_publisher/get_loggers
/raw19/robot_state_publisher/set_logger_level
/raw19/rviz/get_loggers
/raw19/rviz/reload_shaders
/raw19/rviz/set_logger_level
/rosout/get_loggers
/rosout/set_logger_level
```

urdf file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="raw19">

  <material name="blue">
    <color rgba="0.2 0.2 0.8 1"/>
  </material>

  <material name="red">
    <color rgba="0.9 0.0 0.0 1"/>
  </material>

  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="1.57 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.152"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://robot/meshes/RAW.stl" scale="0.005 0.005 0.005"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.175"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.6 0.8 0.35"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <link name="left_wheel">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.01" radius="0.1313"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="red"/>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <joint name="motor1" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="1.0" velocity="0.2"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="left_wheel"/>
    <origin rpy="0.0 1.57 0.0" xyz="0.21 0.0 0.1313"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="right_wheel">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.01" radius="0.1313"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="red"/>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint name="motor2" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="1000.0" velocity="0.5"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="right_wheel"/>
    <origin rpy="0 1.57 0" xyz="-0.21 0.0 0.1313"/>
  </joint>

  <transmission name="left_wheel_transmission">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="motor1">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>  
    </joint>
    <actuator name="left_wheel_actuator">
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
      <hardwareInterface>VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
 
  <transmission name="right_wheel_transmission">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="motor2">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>  
    </joint>
    <actuator name="right_wheel_actuator">
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
      <hardwareInterface>VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>

<gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
    </plugin>
</gazebo>

</robot>
```

I hope that someone can shed some light on why I can't get it to work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313745/how-to-use-controller_manager-with-ros_canopen/) by [rhas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32293/rhas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2019-01-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-01-25**:
What exactly is it that isn't working? What error message if any are you getting?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-25**:\

> I would expect to get at least two services a la '*/command'. Am I wrong to assume this?

The [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller) shows no services at all.

What gave you the impression that you should see services?

**Comment by [rhas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32293/rhas/) on 2019-01-28**:
As stated in Mathias' answer, I misunderstood where the service (that actually was a topic) originated from. I thought it was the controller_manager, but it was the canopen_motor_node once the system was initialized.
Either way, I appreciate the help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The controller manager interface will become available after a successful call to the `init` service (step 7).
You might want to run your launchfile with `roslaunch --screen`  to see all output.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2019-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rhas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32293/rhas/) on 2019-01-28**:
Ah! sry, I should've caught that in the other answer.
It works fine now. I ran into a problem caused by a missing default value in the eds file in 6502, as explained [HERE](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/issues/257). added it in this comment if others have same issue.
Thx again